# Which usage is correct: "program in your university" OR "program at your university"?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to enroll for a program **in** your university.
OR
I would like to enroll for a program **at** your university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are arguably "correct" depending on context, but I would expect to hear (and would probably use) the latter more regularly:

I would like to enroll for a program **at** your university.